# Gracefully terminate the executing line of a bash script

Tags: bash, trap

The manual workflow I want to automate is as follows:

1. `$> adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/file.mp4`
   This starts a recording on a connected Andfroid device and writes it on the device's sd card. This command will never terminate.
2. press ctrl-C: gracefully end the screenrecording
3. `$> adb pull /sdcard/file.mp4` copies the recording from the device to the PC

The above workflow results in a mp4 file that can be played back fine.

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "adb pull /sdcard/file.mp4" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/file.mp4
```

The mp4 file turns out to be corrupt though. It seems the screenrecording is killed rather than gracefully ended.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you know how to gracefully end screenrecord command so the file is not corrupt? First describe that. Than we can try to figure out how to execute other commands.

Comment: Clarified that the manual workflow works as expected